# Flask response to excel file giving corrupt excel file

Tags: flask, pandas.excelwriter

I have a website that has a button. When it's clicked, it returns a number of pandas dataframers into an excel file and returns that excel file automatically as download.

It seems to work ok, except when I open the file, it seems to be corrupted. It asks if some of the tabs should be recovered. I'm using the code below. Any suggestions are appreciated what could be the cause for this.

```
import io
from flask.helpers import make_response
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter

output = io.BytesIO()
writer = ExcelWriter(output)

dfs = [df1,df2....]
tabs ['tab1','tab2',....]

for df, tab_name in zip(dfs, tab_names):
    df.to_excel(writer, tab_name)
writer.close()

resp = make_response(output.getvalue())
resp.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.xlsx'
resp.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
return resp
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to to add

```
output.seek(0)
```

after you close the writer.

You might also find it easier to write

```
return send_file(output, attachment_filename="output.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
```

(after importing `send_file` from `flask`)

Comment: Still having the same issue, although the send_file solution is clearly more elegant.

Comment: Just to ask the obvious question, this is wrapped in an `app.route()`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is wrapped in @app.route

Comment: the problem was that the tab names were too long. output.seek(0) is not necessary

Comment: Huh. Looking back at my code, I'm thinking I copied that bit from prior code that was generating multiple images to save to disk, and left the seek(0) in because why not.